# Computing a complex line integral $dz$ in terms of line integrals $dx$ and $dy$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

**Goal:** I'm trying to verify the calculation claimed by Ahlfors that

$$\int_\gamma f(z)\ dz = \int_\gamma (u\ dx - v\ dy) + i \int_\gamma (u\ dy + v\ dx)$$

**Attempt:**

$$\int_\gamma (u\ dx - v\ dy) + i \int_\gamma (u\ dy + v\ dx) = \int_\gamma u\ dx - \int_\gamma v\ dy + i \int_\gamma u\ dy + i \int_\gamma v\ dx$$

We can now compute each of the terms on the right as follows:

$$\tag{1}
\int_\gamma u\ dx = {1 \over 2} \left(\int_\gamma u\ dz + \overline{\int_\gamma \overline{u}\  dz}  \right) = \int_\gamma u\ dz$$

$$\tag{2}
-\int_\gamma v\ dy = -{1 \over 2i}\left(\int_\gamma v\ dz - \overline{\int_\gamma \overline{v} \ dz}  \right) = 0$$

$$\tag{3}
i \int_\gamma u\ dy =   i{1 \over 2i}\left(\int_\gamma u\ dz - \overline{\int_\gamma \overline{u} \ dz}  \right) = 0$$

$$\tag{4}
i \int_\gamma v\ dx = i \int_\gamma v\ dz$$

so that we now obtain:

$$\int_\gamma u\ dx - \int_\gamma v\ dy + i \int_\gamma u\ dy + i \int_\gamma v\ dx = \int_\gamma u\ dz +  i \int_\gamma v\ dz = \int_\gamma f(z)\ dz$$

so that we have

$$\int_\gamma (u\ dx - v\ dy) + i \int_\gamma (u\ dy + v\ dx) = \int_\gamma u\ dz +  i \int_\gamma v\ dz = \int_\gamma f(z)\ dz$$

as desired.

**Question:** Are there any flaws in my above reasoning, especially in
equations (1)-(4) above?

Comment: Equations $(1)$ and $(3)$ are equivalent, and don't always hold. Similar for $(2)$ and $(4)$. You can just compute $$f(z)\cdot dz = (u(z) + iv(z))\cdot (dx+idy) = (u(z)\cdot dx - v(z)\cdot dy) + i(u(z)\cdot dy + v(z)\cdot dx).$$ At some point one has to verify that that computation is formally correct, but to get and understand the results, the proof of correctness is not absolutely necessary.

Comment: Very helpful -- now I see what's going on.  From this it seems apparent that $\int_\gamma u\ dx - v\ dy \in \mathbb{R}$ while $i \int_\gamma u\ dx + v\ dy \in \mathbb{C}$.  I assume this is the central point of expressing $\int_\gamma f\ dz$ this way (i.e., separating the strictly real and strictly complex components of the line integral).  Is this correct?